# Tag synonym request: [multilingual] and [multi-lingual]

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

These two tags on Stack Overflow should be merged and one should be a synonym of the other.  They both have the same meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [multi-lingual](/questions/tagged/multi-lingual) only had a few questions attached. Since "multilingual" appears to be a proper English word according to online dictionaries, I went and changed all those questions to [multilingual](/questions/tagged/multilingual).

The Orphan Tag Reaper should take care of deleting the hyphen tag within 24h.

Comment: Thanks.  It seems that this request is resolved.